# Brother DCP-J315W - scanner not working on Windows when using WIA drivers

Tags: windows-10, drivers, printer, scanner, brother-printer

I was using [NAPS2](https://www.naps2.com/) to scan documents on my Brother DCP-J315W all-in-one (over wi-fi). It was configured in such way that WIA driver was used. My OS is Windows 10 PRO x64 (v.2004).

Suddenly scanning stopped working one day:

```
NAPS2.Scan.Exceptions.ScanDriverUnknownException: An error occurred with the scanning driver. ---> NAPS2.Scan.Wia.Native.WiaException: WIA error code 80004005
   at NAPS2.Scan.Wia.Native.WiaTransfer.Download()
   at NAPS2.Scan.Wia.WiaScanOperation.DoTransfer(Concrete source, WiaDevice device, WiaItem item)
   at NAPS2.Scan.Wia.WiaScanOperation.Scan(Concrete source)
   at NAPS2.Scan.Wia.WiaScanOperation.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<Start>b__0()
```

I switched to test to TWAIN and the scan worked again.

Since then I have followed these steps:

1. Checked scanning functionalities in Paint, Paint .NET and "Fax & Scan" applications - they all failed. Scanner and buttons were active, but an error occurred after initializing the scan.
2. Reinstalled printer drivers (removed by Brother's application, by control panel and devices manager). I firstly used drivers from Windows update, but only printer functionality was installed with this approach. Then I tried install [Windows 10 x64 driver](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=pl&lang=pl&prod=dcpj315w_eu_as&os=10013) and [Windows 7 x64 driver](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=pl&lang=pl&prod=dcpj315w_eu_as&os=93). None of them helped.
3. Turned on SMB 1.0 feature in Windows.
4. Restarted these services: Windows Image Acquisition (WIA), Shell Hardware Detection and Remote Procedure Call (RPC).
5. Used Windows 10 troubleshooter tool. It found some problem with printer, but didn't specify what it was. After that it concluded that it couldn't solve the problem.

The printer as such works flawlessly. The problem is only with scanner and WIA driver.

Does anyone know what else I can check? What might be the reason that the driver does not work?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a factory reset of the printer's network settings, as follows:

> Make sure the machine is not operating, then disconnect all the cables
> from the machine (except the power cord).
>
> Press Menu.
>
> Press the up or down arrow key to choose Network and press OK.
>
> Press the up or down arrow key to choose Factory Reset or Network
> Reset and press OK.
>
> - For MFC users: Press 1 for Reset.
> - For DCP users: Press + for Reset.
> - For MFC users: Press 1 for Reboot.
> - For DCP users: Press + for Reboot.
>
> The machine will restart, re-connect cables once this is complete.

For Touchscreen models:

> Make sure the machine is not operating, then disconnect all the cables
> from the machine (except the power cord).
>
> Press MENU.
>
> Press Network.
>
> If Network Reset is in the options, press Network Reset. If not, press
> the up or down arrow key to display Factory Reset or Network Reset and
> press Factory Reset or Network Reset.
>
> Press Yes.
>
> Hold down Yes for 2 seconds to confirm.
>
> The machine will restart, re-connect cables once this is complete

From [Brother's FAQs & Troubleshooting](https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=dcpj315w_eu_as&faqid=faq00000105_015). Note that you will have to re-connect the printer to your network after this.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried a network reset and then re-connected the printer to my network. Sadly, problems still exists.

It looks for my like some problem with my Windows and its configuration. I tried scanning from another notebook and it worked correctly.